# Why zero in array in C++ is considered as NULL(using CODEBLOCKS)?

Tags: c++, null, codeblocks

I've entered zero as an integer in an array and when using a function to print array (show()) it exits the function considering the ZERO as NULL.

**array = {1,2,3,0,4,5}**

**expected output = 1 2 3 0 4 5**

**output = 1 2 3**

Why is it so?
Is something wrong with the CodeBlocks settings?

Thank you

```
 int show(int arr[])                               //p r i n t   a r r a y
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; arr[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
    if(arr[0]=='\0')
        cout<<"Emptry Array";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but since the array holds `int` values, it would be clearer to compare those values to another `int` value. That is, change `arr[i] != '\0'` to `arr[i] != 0`. And similarly for the expression in the `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> expected output = 1 2 3 0 4 5
>
> output = 1 2 3
>
> Why is it so?

In short: Because your loop stops when it encounters an element that is equal to `'\0'` and `0 == '\0'`.

To clarify, `'\0'` is a character literal with the value 0. Character types are integer types. Furthermore, `NULL` is a macro that expands to a null pointer constant. `NULL` macro wasn't used in the example program at all.

Note that if you were to pass a pointer to an array that doesn't contain 0, then the loop would not end before reaching the end of the array, and would consequently overflow it, and the behaviour of the program would be undefined.

> What shall I use instead?

If you want to iterate over 6 elements of an array, then you can use a loop such as this:

```
std::size_t count = 6;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

> any general way to reach the last element in an integer array?

The index of the last element is the number of elements in the array minus one.

> Just to append it.

There is no way to append to an array. Size of an array remains constant through the lifetime of the array.

> Is something wrong with the CodeBlocks settings?

I see no reason to suspect that.

Comment: Plus one for the last bit in particular. Golden rule is to never blame your environment.

Comment: @eerorika What shall I use instead?

Comment: @eerorika any general way to reach the last element in an integer array? Just to append it.

Answer (score 4):

`'\0'` is a `char` type constant with the numerical value 0.

Compare that with `0` which is an `int` type constant with the numerical value 0. (Interesting fact: it's actually an *octal* constant since it starts with a `0`!)

Some folk use `NULL` to denote zero too, particularly when working with pointers. In C++ it needs to be set to strictly 0,  or a *prvalue* of type `std::nullptr_t`. (Compare to C where `(void*)0` is often the definition.)

From C++11 you should use `nullptr` to denote a null pointer value.

---

Many folk use 0, `\0`, NULL, and `nullptr` in a haphazard manner without regards to what they denote. Take the above as a guide.

Comment: `In C++ [NULL] needs to be set to strictly 0.` Not quite true. It may be any null pointer constant. Since C++11, `nullptr` is also a null pointer literal and is consequently allowed definition for the `NULL` macro.

Comment: @eerorika: Oops. Put in the other alternative.

Comment: @Bathsheba Noted. But using nullptr is throwing an error.

Comment: @ayush7ad6 error id a desirable outcome when one tries to use null pointer constant in a context where it isn't meaningul.

Answer (score 2):

> I've entered zero as an integer in an array and when using a function to print array (show()) it exits the function considering the ZERO as NULL. Why is it so?

In this case it's used to signal the end of the array (since there is no other way for the function to know where the array ends). `'\0'`, that is a `char` that will be promoted to an `int` with the value `0`, is used as a special value which should *not* be a part of the normal data. Since you are expected to treat `0` as just any other `int` that won't work. **`int`s do not have a *null* state** - they only have integer values.

---

This is a very *`C`-like* way to pass data around. Much like the below, which supports having `0` as a value in the array:

```
int show(int arr[], size_t array_length)
{
    if(array_length == 0) cout<<"Empty Array";
    else for(size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
    return 0; // why does this function return anything? Make it void.
}
```